# appendgrid - Getting grid data as a JSON Object instead of regular serialization

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the example listed here, how can I get the grid data as JSON?

[Reference Link](https://appendgrid.apphb.com/Demo/Basic)

The JQuery Serialize works, but it would be nice if I am able to get each row as a JSON Object, so I can parse the data.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.appendGrid('getAllValue')` function to get the grid data as javascript objects. You can parse them directly or encode them as JSON.

Example:

`var data = $('#tblAppendGrid').appendGrid('getAllValue')`
returns an array where each element is the data from one table row as object.

`data[0]` will be the first row.

`JSON.stringify(data)` will be a JSON string with all the data from your table

Answer (score 0):

You can create element on run time, as per the JSON object length, you have to use for each or simple for loop and iterate the json data upto length.

Like :

```
 for(var i=0; i<=json_object.length; i++) {
 console.log(json_object.user[i].name);  var ele_block =
 document.createElement('div'); $(ele_block).addClass("block"+i);
 ele_block.appendChild(block_name);
 $("#name_block").append(ele_block);         
 }
```

Create an element where the newly generated data will be added.

```
<div id="name_block"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just use JQuery Serialize to get the seriesed string and then use the helper function `uri_decoder` to decode it to an Object.

```
var decode, seriesed, uri_decoder;

seriesed = "a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5";

uri_decoder = function(component_unpacker) {
  if (component_unpacker == null) {
    component_unpacker = (function(s) {
      return s;
    });
  }
  return function(str) {
    var d, i, j, k, len, ref, ref1, ref2, s, v;
    d = {};
    ref1 = (ref = str.match(/[^?=&]+=[^&]*/g)) != null ? ref : [];
    for (i = 0, len = ref1.length; i < len; i++) {
      s = ref1[i];
      ref2 = s.match(/([^=]+)=(.*)/), j = ref2.length - 2, k = ref2[j++], v = ref2[j++];
      d[decodeURIComponent(k)] = component_unpacker(decodeURIComponent(v));
    }
    return d;
  };
};

decode = uri_decoder();

console.log(json(decode(seriesed)));
```

try these code [here](http://luochen1990.me/try_coffee?#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)

this util is provided by [this](https://github.com/luochen1990/coffee-mate/blob/master/src/url-helpers.coffee) project.